# get count of common string from two RDD in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intersection, rdd

I have 2 RDD i.e. `RDD[String]` andd `RDD[String,String]` and their content are as following.

```
RDD[String]                     RDD[String,String]
mobile                          laptop,aa
smartphone                      printer,bb
desktop                         scanner,ya
laptop                          mobile,gb
printer                         burger,gn
```

I need to intersect this two RDD and need to get count of common keyword.
My output should be `3` because printer,laptop and mobile are comman.

I tried with `intersection()` but didn't get it. I have done with this array but don't know how to do with RDD(because i need to work on RDD).

Here what I have tried.

```
tokenArray.intersect(param._1.split("/")).size > 2)
```

Please give me reference or hint.

Comment: Not sure what you were trying with that `intersection` but it takes an RDD as an argument, not   a predicate.

Comment: And that predicate doesn't fit your problem description at all. There are no `\` in your example data, for instance. Please edit your question to a MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Does the following solves your problem?

```scala
val keywords = sc.parallelize(Seq("mobile", "smartphone", "desktop", "laptop", "printer"))
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(("laptop", "aa"), ("printer", "bb"), ("scanner", "ya"),
  ("mobile", "gb"), ("burger", "gn")))

val keysInData = data.map(_._1)

val result = keywords.intersection(keysInData).count()
```